# adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing... ADB server didn't ACK

Tags: android, react-native

```
I am developing sample application and installation procedure followed 
as followed react-native document and installed this application but 
ios  wokring fine and coming to android getting this issue.
```

adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (40); killing...
    ADB server didn't ACK
    Full server startup log: /var/folders/df/3drfx_117t1g7d97fxd86j_w0000gn/T//adb.501.log
    Server had pid: 14441
    --- adb starting (pid 14441) ---
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14441 194054 main.cpp:56] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.40
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14441 194054 main.cpp:56] Version 4986621
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14441 194054 main.cpp:56] Installed as /usr/local/bin/adb
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14441 194054 main.cpp:56] 
    --- adb starting (pid 14443) ---
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14443 194061 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14443 194061 main.cpp:57] Version 0.0.1-4500957
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14443 194061 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/praveen/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
    adb I 10-30 20:55:55 14443 194061 main.cpp:57] 
    adb I 10-30 20:55:56 14441 194054 auth.cpp:421] adb_auth_init...
    adb I 10-30 20:55:56 14441 194054 auth.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/praveen/.android/adbkey'...
    error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use
    adb server killed by remote request

```
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
Starting the app (/Users/praveen/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/com.awesomeproject.MainActivity...
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup log: /var/folders/df/3drfx_117t1g7d97fxd86j_w0000gn/T//adb.501.log
Server had pid: 14447
--- adb starting (pid 14447) ---
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14447 194321 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14447 194321 main.cpp:57] Version 0.0.1-4500957
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14447 194321 main.cpp:57] Installed as /Users/praveen/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14447 194321 main.cpp:57] 
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14445 194315 adb_auth_host.cpp:416] adb_auth_init...
adb I 10-30 20:55:57 14445 194315 adb_auth_host.cpp:174] read_key_file '/Users/praveen/.android/adbkey'...
error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: Address already in use

* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
Srikanth:AwesomeProject Srikanth$
```

Please help me this  This is not run at this emulator ! *emphasized text*

Comment: If none of the solution works, Restart the system. It works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I resolved my issue

I had given to *local.properties* file added in android folder 
gave sdk.dir = xxxxxxxxxxxxx

and 
just open our **~/.bash_profile**

added these commands :

```
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

save the bash profile 
give the coomand to run-react-native android

Answer (score 4):

You gotta kill and start your adb, I have often this message when connecting to device via adb over the network.
To do so, run in terminal/adb whatever you use:
`adb kill-server`

`adb start-server`
Then check if your device is avaible from the list via `adb devices`. In windows/Mac you must use `.` (Mac) `./` (Windows) before typing commands.

Comment: i used .adb kill-server like before . and both comments not working for me

Comment: Running into the same problem. Only restarting computer worked for me.